# PHP Loop with Multiple Nested SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables and I wish to display all the contents but grouping together the contents by a certain field - the job_id field:

The two tables:

> - job_experience
>
> job_id (Primary Key) 
>   job_name
>   user_id
>
> - job_skills
>
> skill_id (Primary Key) 
>   job_id 
>   skill_name

This should produce by matching both tables job_ids:

> Job Name 1 
>   Skill 1 
>   Skill 2
>
> Job Name 2 
>   Skill 1

I currently have the working loop for the Experience table, but I'm unable to determine how to also include the job_skills and group it together via job_id.  I attempted a nested loop with a SQL query focused on matching the job_ids, but this did not work.

```
<?php

$experience_sql =mysql_query("select e.job_id, e.job_name,from   job_experience e where e.user_id='$user_id_session'", $connection);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($experience_sql)) {
    ?>
<textarea cols="50" rows="10">
<?php
    echo $row['job_name']." "."\n";

    ?>
    </textarea>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Sounds like you want some `join` some tables together.

Comment: Don't use mysql_query as it doesn't exists as of php7 and it is very insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query to get all skills in relation to jobs as a comma separated list:

```
SELECT e.job_id, e.job_name, GROUP_CONCAT(s.job_skills)
FROM job_experience e
LEFT JOIN job_skills s ON e.job_id = s.job_id
GROUP BY e.job_id
```

Comment: Hi, the GROUP_CONCAT was exactly what I was looking for.

    $experience_sql = mysql_query("select e.job_id, e.company, s.skill, GROUP_CONCAT(s.skill) as skill2 from job_experience e inner join job_skills s on e.job_id=s.job_id WHERE e.user_id = 1 GROUP BY e.job_id='$user_id_session' ",$connection);

This worked exactly as required!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for the statement like this

```
select e.job_id, e.job_name,s.skill_name from   job_experience e, job_skills s where e.job_id=s.job_id and e.user_id='$user_id_session'
```

or

```
select e.job_id, e.job_name,s.skill_name from   job_experience e inner join job_skills s on e.job_id=s.job_id where e.user_id='$user_id_session'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$experience_sql = mysql_query("select e.job_id, e.job_name, s.skill_name from job_experience e inner join job_skills s on e.job_id=s.job_id where e.user_id='$user_id_session' ",$connection);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($experience_sql)){
   ?>
 <textarea cols="50" rows="10">
<?php
echo $row['job_name']." "."\n";
 echo $row['skill_name']." "."\n";

?>
</textarea>
<?php
}
?>
```